# Is this a correct JPA Criteria Query

Tags: jpa, jpql

```
   public User getUserByName(String uName){              

    TypedQuery<User> query =  em.createQuery(
            "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.name = :uName", User.class);
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

I'm wondering if that is correct syntax? If not can you show me how to do it right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any exception or you haven't tried yet. Query looks syntactically correct, you might have forgotten to set parameter `uName`

Comment: Thanks Nayan. I'm accessing the Bean using JNDI AND I couldn't run and check it as I have trouble with my glassfish server currently.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28613_01/apirefs.1211/e24396/ejb3_langref.html), but it is not Criteria Query. Later refers usually to queries done with [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/package-summary.html). Though with some provider/database combinations it can be problematic if *user* is reserved word.